# TFX's Evaluator Component cannot prepare the inputs for evaluation

Tags: tensorflow, tfx

I am using tfx pipeline for training and evaluating an autoencoder. The data that I have is basically 5 arrays of size (15,1) that I concatenate and put together and pass to the model.

In order to keep track of the training data, I defined the mean value of these parameters in my **ExampleGen** component. So, I have both `feature1` and `feature1_mean` in my input features, however, after the **Transform** component, I remove the `*_mean` features from the data.

Now, after I train my model and want to pass it to the Evaluator, this error comes up:

```
unable to prepare inputs for evaluation: input_specs={
'feature1': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 15, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
'feature2': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 15, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
'feature3': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 15, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
'feature4': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 15, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)}, 
features={
'feature1_mean': array([3.4559317, 3.528199 , 3.3727243, 3.0274842, 3.2321723, 3.339905 , 3.3501785, 2.987716 , 3.236495 , 3.5900073, 3.1439974, 3.1659212, ...], dtype=float32), 
'feature2_mean': array([1.5840595 , 1.6105878 , 1.5401138 , 1.2408142 , 1.2962327 ,], dtype=float32), 
'feature3_mean': array([1.5840595 , 1.6105878 , 1.5401138 , 1.2408142 , 1.2962327 ,....]}
[while running 'ExtractEvaluateAndWriteResults/ExtractAndEvaluate/EvaluateMetricsAndPlots/ComputeMetricsAndPlots()/CombineMetricsPerSlice/WindowIntoDiscarding']
```

Here is the configuration that I am using for my eval_config:

```
eval_config = tfma.EvalConfig(
    model_specs=[
        tfma.ModelSpec(
            signature_name='serving_default',
            label_key='feature1_mean',
            preprocessing_function_names=['transform_features'],
            )
        ],
    metrics_specs=[
        tfma.MetricsSpec(
            metrics=[
                tfma.MetricConfig(class_name='ExampleCount'),
            ]
        )
    ],
    slicing_specs=[
        tfma.SlicingSpec()
    ])
```

I am just passing `feature1_mean` as a dummy parameter name here, cause I have no label key in fact as it is an unsupervised learning model.

The signatures that I am saving are:

```
def _get_tf_examples_serving_signature(model, tf_transform_output):
    """Returns a serving signature that accepts `tensorflow.Example`."""

    # We need to track the layers in the model in order to save it.
    # TODO(b/162357359): Revise once the bug is resolved.
    model.tft_layer_inference = tf_transform_output.transform_features_layer()

    @tf.function(input_signature=[
      tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string, name='examples')
    ])
    def serve_tf_examples_fn(serialized_tf_example):
        """Returns the output to be used in the serving signature."""
        raw_feature_spec = tf_transform_output.raw_feature_spec()
        # Remove label feature since these will not be present at serving time.
        raw_features = tf.io.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, raw_feature_spec)
        
        raw_features.pop('feature1_mean')
        raw_features.pop('feature2_mean')
        raw_features.pop('feature3_mean')
        raw_features.pop('feature4_mean')
        transformed_features = model.tft_layer_inference(raw_features)
        logging.info('serve_transformed_features = %s', transformed_features)
        result = model(transformed_features)
        # TODO(b/154085620): Convert the predicted labels from the model using a
        # reverse-lookup (opposite of transform.py).
        return {'outputs': result}

    return serve_tf_examples_fn

def _get_transform_features_signature(model, tf_transform_output):
    """Returns a serving signature that applies tf.Transform to features."""

    # We need to track the layers in the model in order to save it.
    # TODO(b/162357359): Revise once the bug is resolved.
    model.tft_layer_eval = tf_transform_output.transform_features_layer()

    @tf.function(input_signature=[
      tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string, name='examples')
    ])
    def transform_features_fn(serialized_tf_example):
        """Returns the transformed_features to be fed as input to evaluator."""
        raw_feature_spec = tf_transform_output.raw_feature_spec()
        raw_features = tf.io.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, raw_feature_spec)
        transformed_features = model.tft_layer_eval(raw_features)
        logging.info('eval_transformed_features = %s', transformed_features)
        return transformed_features

    return transform_features_fn
```

I'd really appreciate it if you can help me solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that I found about the TFMA library and TFX's Evaluator component, in general, is that the output key has to be one-dimensional, and there has to be a label key alway.
If you want to make it work for auto-encoders, instead of making changes to the `_input_fn`, in the Transform component, return the input twice with two different keys.
For example, if your input key for an image is `img`, return `img_input` and `img_output` in your Transform component. This way, you don't need to manipulate the Trainer component's `input_fn`, and in the Evaluator, you can easily use the `img_output` key as your label.
However, as mentioned earlier, this `img_output` has to be one-dimensional. if in your model, you're using Conv2D layers to encode and decode your image, I'd recommend using the one-dimensional data at first but adding a Reshape layer to make it ready for subsequent Conv2D layers.

Example:

```
    encoder_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(60,), name='input_xf')
    x = layers.Reshape((15, 4))(encoder_inputs)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filter_num*2, 3, activation="relu",
                      strides=2, padding="valid")(x)
    z = layers.Dense(latent_dim)(x)

    encoder = tf.keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z], name="encoder")

    latent_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    x = layers.Conv1DTranspose(4, 3, padding="same")(x)
    decoder_outputs = layers.Reshape((60,))(x)
    decoder = tf.keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
```